# Django model object's construction fails silently

Tags: python, django, model

I have quite an obvious piece of code that fails:

```
temp = MyModel(
    required_field1 = AnotherModel.objects.filter(name="example1")[0],
    required_field2 = YetAnotherModel.objects.filter(name="example2")[0],
)
```

The problem is that after that, temp is set to `None`! I have no traceback, no error message - it just doesn't work and leaves `None`. `required_fieldNs (for N=1|2)` are the only mandatory fields in `MyModel`. Objects of `AnotherModel` and `YetAnotherModel` exist. Does anyone have any idea why it doesn't work as I'd like to (I mean it does not construct a new object, referenced  by temp). I can't paste all my actual code in here, because it is a corporate project, but if in doubt - please ask and I can explain probably something more.
EDIT:
OK I figured out why it fails, the problem was that I was trying to invoke a method from that newly constructed object and it caused it to crash in this strange way. This topic can now be closed.

Comment: Have you tried breaking the statement out into pieces, and checking that everything's okay step by step? So do both the ORM lookups before you create the model instance (and print something about each of them so you know it's worked). Failing that, does your exact code fail in the `manage.py shell` REPL?

Comment: Yeah, it breaks even in manage.py shell

Answer (score 0):

Unless `required_field1` and `required_field2` are foreign keys, the above code won't work.

Are you sure you didn't mean:

```
temp = MyModel(
    required_field1 = unicode(AnotherModel.objects.filter(name="example1")[0]),
    required_field2 = unicode(YetAnotherModel.objects.filter(name="example2")[0]),
)
```

Or:

```
temp = MyModel(
    required_field1 = AnotherModel.objects.filter(name="example1")[0].some_field,
    required_field2 = YetAnotherModel.objects.filter(name="example2")[0].some_field,
)
```

Comment: What is that? It is not standard django field type.